# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) in python thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

I randomly get Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) while my thread function is running. My program made on pyqt5 and have function that downloads videos from YouTube with yt-dlp and when I try to download some videos, I get this error, sometimes the function itself is executed completely without errors, but at the end of its execution, an error still appears.

**My func**

```
    def DOWNLOAD(self):
        if not self.LINEEDIT_LINK.text() == '' and _FILE_SIZE > 0:
            self.PUSHBUTTON_DOWNLOAD.setEnabled(False)
            self.PUSHBUTTON_DOWNLOAD.setStyleSheet(set_download_button_font_size(14))

            downloadThread = Thread(target=self.download_thread)
            downloadThread.daemon = True
            downloadThread.start()

      


    def my_hook(self, d):
        if d['status'] == 'downloading':
            self.__cleen_percent(dl=d)
        elif d['status'] == 'finished':

            self.PROGRESSBAR.setValue(0)
            self.PUSHBUTTON_DOWNLOAD.setText("Download")
            self.PUSHBUTTON_DOWNLOAD.setCheckable(True)

    def __cleen_percent(self, dl):
        network_speed = dl['_speed_str']
        percent = dl['_percent_str']
        all_mb = round(dl['total_bytes_estimate'] / 1024 / 1024, 2)
        downloaded_mb = round(dl['downloaded_bytes'] / 1024 / 1024, 2)
        eta = dl['eta']

        for i, char in enumerate(percent):
            if char == '%':
                value = percent[i - 5:i + 1].replace('%', '')
                value = (float(value.replace(' ', '')))
                self.PROGRESSBAR.setValue(int(value))
                self.PUSHBUTTON_DOWNLOAD.setText(
                    f'{network_speed} | {downloaded_mb} MB / {all_mb} MB | eta: {eta} secs')
                break

    # YOUTUBE THREADS

    def download_thread(self):

        try:

            ydl_opts_download = {
                'outtmpl': FOLDER_TO_SAVE + '/%(title)s.%(ext)s',
                'format': f"bv*[height<={_RESOLUTION}][ext={_VIDEO_FORMAT}]+ba[ext=m4a]/b[height<={_RESOLUTION}][ext={_VIDEO_FORMAT}] / bv*+ba/b",
                'progress_hooks': [self.my_hook],
            }

            ydl_opts_download_auto = {
                'outtmpl': FOLDER_TO_SAVE + '/%(title)s.%(ext)s',
                'format': f"bv*[height<={_RESOLUTION}]+ba[ext=m4a]/b[height<={_RESOLUTION}] / bv*+ba/b",
                'progress_hooks': [self.my_hook],
            }

            ydl_opts_download_maxres = {
                'outtmpl': FOLDER_TO_SAVE + '/%(title)s.%(ext)s',
                'format': f"bv*[ext={_VIDEO_FORMAT}]+ba[ext=m4a]/b[ext={_VIDEO_FORMAT}] / bv*+ba/b",
                'progress_hooks': [self.my_hook],
            }

            ydl_opts_download_maxres_auto = {
                'outtmpl': FOLDER_TO_SAVE + '/%(title)s.%(ext)s',
                'format': f"bv*+ba[ext=m4a]/b / bv*+ba/b",
                'progress_hooks': [self.my_hook],
            }

            if FILE_TYPE == 0:
                if MAX_RESOLUTION is True:
                    with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts_download_maxres_auto) as ydl:
                        ydl.download([_URL])
                else:
                    with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts_download_auto) as ydl:
                        ydl.download([_URL])
            else:
                if MAX_RESOLUTION is True:
                    with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts_download_maxres) as ydl:
                        ydl.download([_URL])

                else:
                    with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts_download) as ydl:
                        ydl.download([_URL])

            if OPEN_FOLDER is True:
                startfile(FOLDER_TO_SAVE)
            if NOTIFICATIONS is True:
                match LANGUAGE:
                    case 0:
                        toast.show_toast(
                            "Youtube Downloader",
                            "Video downloaded",
                            duration=5,
                            threaded=True,
                            icon_path=load_file("icons/youtube-downloader-icon.ico"),
                        )
                    case 1:
                        toast.show_toast(
                            "Youtube Downloader",
                            "Видео скачано",
                            duration=5,
                            threaded=True,
                            icon_path=load_file("icons/youtube-downloader-icon.ico"),
                        )

            if CLOSE_APP is True:
                QCoreApplication.quit()

            self.PUSHBUTTON_DOWNLOAD.setEnabled(True)
            self.PUSHBUTTON_DOWNLOAD.setStyleSheet(set_download_button_font_size(16))

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            self.PUSHBUTTON_DOWNLOAD.setEnabled(True)
            self.PUSHBUTTON_DOWNLOAD.setStyleSheet(set_download_button_font_size(16))
```

**Here is the terminal output while download_thread is running**

```
[youtube] YBBbNbumaoM: Downloading webpage
[youtube] YBBbNbumaoM: Downloading android player API JSON
[youtube] YBBbNbumaoM: Downloading MPD manifest
[info] YBBbNbumaoM: Downloading 1 format(s): 248+140
[dashsegments] Total fragments: 111
[download] Destination: E:\code\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\YOUTUBE_DOWNLOADER_2\videos\Free Bird Isolated Guitar Track HQ.f248.webm
[download]  37.8% of ~  11.91MiB at  933.49KiB/s ETA 00:08 (frag 42/111)Windows fatal exception: access violation

Thread 0x00002544 (most recent call first):
  File "E:\code\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\YOUTUBE_DOWNLOADER_2\downloader.py", line 1184 in __cleen_percent
  File "E:\code\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\YOUTUBE_DOWNLOADER_2\downloader.py", line 1166 in my_hook
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\downloader\common.py", line 459 in _hook_progress
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\downloader\fragment.py", line 284 in frag_progress_hook
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\downloader\common.py", line 459 in _hook_progress
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\downloader\http.py", line 314 in download
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\downloader\http.py", line 377 in real_download
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\downloader\common.py", line 444 in download
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\downloader\fragment.py", line 124 in _download_fragment
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\downloader\fragment.py", line 469 in download_fragment
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\downloader\fragment.py", line 521 in download_and_append_fragments
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\downloader\fragment.py", line 382 in download_and_append_fragments_multiple
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\downloader\dash.py", line 60 in real_download
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\downloader\common.py", line 444 in download
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 2970 in dl
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 3229 in process_info
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 2779 in process_video_result
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 1674 in process_ie_result
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 1615 in __extract_info
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 1518 in wrapper
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 1507 in extract_info
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 3344 in wrapper
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 3369 in download
  File "E:\code\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\YOUTUBE_DOWNLOADER_2\downloader.py", line 1222 in download_thread
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\threading.py", line 975 in run
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\threading.py", line 1038 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "E:\code\Python\Lib\threading.py", line 995 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00002cb0 (most recent call first):
  File "E:\code\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\YOUTUBE_DOWNLOADER_2\downloader.py", line 1451 in <module>
[download]  39.6% of ~  11.92MiB at   49.16KiB/s ETA 00:11 (frag 44/111)
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

When I run the same function without a thread and try to download the same video, the function runs without errors and downloads the video, but in this case the program interface does not respond while the function is running

Comment: Widgets are not thread safe, and should *never* be accessed from external threads. If you want to properly interact with the UI from a thread, implement a QThread (or a QObject moved to a QThread) and use custom signals.

Comment: And, by the way, this is true of every Ui framework on all the major platforms.  UI stuff all has to be done from the primary thread.  UI frameworks work via message passing, and the message queue is associated with a thread.